# Python: automatically delete class object after return statement

Tags: python, class, memory, return, code-cleanup

I have a class that contains a function inside which I build and store a potentially very large bumpy array which I read form an HDF5 file. (I store the array as a class object so that when I read the various HDF5 datasets from the file I can use a list comprehension rather than a manual loop.) What I would like is to return and delete the stored array simultaneously (i.e. clean up the memory after the return statement).

```
class MWE(object):
      def __init__(self,*args):
          pass
          return

      def example(self,**kwargs):
          self.array = readLargeArrayFromHDF5File(...)
          return self.array # And simultaneously clean up self.array?
```

I know that I could simply delete the array using something like `del MWE.array` later on in my script, but is there any way to automatically clean up without me having to remember to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm still learning so could use some clarification of how/if class objects are cleaned up upon return. Will self.array be cleared from memory? (As the MWE class will still exist...) I just want to avoid doing "array2 = MWE.example()" and then using twice the memory...

Comment: Wait why would you return an array and then delete it immediately. You do know that the same object is passed to the caller and not a copy of it? Also del is deleting the reference to the object, you would not be saving any actual memory.

Comment: @aim Oh, just saw your comment. So those are references not copies. When copying an object in python you usually have to do something really explicit like `list_A_copy = list(list_A)` or `dict_A_copy = {key:value for key,value in dict_A.items()}`

Comment: Ah, ok -- thanks all for the clarification. @GiannisSpiliopoulos --  so if I wanted to do: "array2 = numpy.copy(MWE.example())", how would I delete the self.array from memory? (But leave the class intact so that I could extract other attributes if needed...)

Comment: Well you can delete the reference with a del statement and then force an explicit garbage collection `import gc` and then `gc.collect()`

Comment: Ok, and I am guessing that there is no command or method to do automatic garbage collection of self.array at the same time as numpy.copy()? (So that I do not have both self.array and array2 stored in memory.)

Comment: Why use `self.array` at all if you don't want to keep it as a persistent attribute of the class? Methods can create and return local variables which don't have the `self` prefix. Then garbage collection of those local variables will naturally follow method return. There is no reason to prematurely optimize memory use. Wait to see if there is an actual problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman -- I have a class to read HDF5 files of a particular data structure and I need to loop over many dataset names. This reading may be called many times (reading hundreds of files) and so I was using list comprehensions to update self.array rather than having to use manual for-loops. I'd show my full script but it is pretty far from a MWE!

Comment: When you are done with `self.array` and you want to return it, you could 1) assign it to a local variable in the method, 2) set `self.array` equal to an empty array, 3) return the local variable to the caller. When the caller is done with it, it will be garbage-collected. Do you have a C++ background? Your question reminds me of things you need to worry about with that language.

Comment: @JohnColeman -- ok, thanks, will try those methods. No, no C++ background (even worse, Fortan background!) :P

Answer (score 3):

you ned to use [**context manager**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) for this kind of stuff! it automatically clears object when it gets out of the `with` code block.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


class MWE(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass
        return

    @contextmanager
    def example(self, **kwargs):
        array = readLargeArrayFromHDF5File(...)
        try:
            yield array
        finally:
            array = None

    @contextmanager
    def example_two(self, **kwargs):
        array = readLargeArrayFromHDF5File(...)
        try:
            for item in array:
                yield item
        finally:
            array = None
# usage
with mwe_obj.example_two(kwargs) as result:
    for r in result:
        # work with your result here
        print (r)

# when your code hits this block self.array would get set to None
print ('cleared large array')
```